# ddm-date sent from liferay to solr is not parsed as date

Tags: date, solr, liferay-6

In Liferay 6.2 I have added a new field to structure with type: ddm-date. Next, after creating an article with that structure, it is sent to Solr 4.6. Unfortunately, data sent to Solr has incorrect date format. It looks that Liferay sends it as `java.util.Date.toString()` `e.g.: Fri Mar 29 00:00:00 CET 2019.`

I have tried to parse incoming data in solr. This is what I've tried:

1.Adding dateTimeFormat to field description in schema.xml:

```
<field indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="ddm/79280/realPublishDate_pl_PL" dateTimeFormat="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" stored="true" type="date" />
```

This gives me error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Schema Parsing Failed: Invalid field property: dateTimeFormat.
```

2.Adding processor to updateRequestProcessorChain in solrconfig.xml like this:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="replica">
    <processor class="solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldName">ddm/79280/realPublishDate_pl_PL</str>
        <str name="format">
            <str>EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy</str>
        </str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
<requestHandler class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" name="/update">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="update.chain">replica</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

This gives me error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error while creating field 'ddm/79280/realPublishDate_pl_PL{type=date,properties=indexed,stored,omitNorms,multiValued,sortMissingLast}' from value 'Sat May 11 00:00:00 CEST 2019'
```

So it looks that this processor is not chained to parsing process at all?

No ideas what to try next. Any help will be appreciated.